# What is is the correct way to update vertices and send them to GPU?

Tags: qt, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to draw a line strip with points from user clicks on a QOpenGLWidget. If I put vertices manually and do not update them, it works as expected, but if I update my vector of Vertex, it only draws a line from center to the right center of the widget, regardless of vertices location. This is my updateVertices method (called when a user clicks on the widget):

```
void CurveGLWidget::updateVertices()
{
    m_vao.bind();
    m_vbo.bind();

    m_vbo.allocate(vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));
    m_vbo.write(0, &vertices.begin(), vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));

    m_program.enableAttributeArray("position");
    m_program.setAttributeBuffer("position", GL_FLOAT, 0, 2, sizeof(Vertex));

    m_program.enableAttributeArray("color");
    m_program.setAttributeBuffer("color", GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec2), 4, sizeof(Vertex));

    m_vao.release();
    m_vbo.release();
}
```

at this point m_vao and m_vbo are already created.

This is my paintGL method:

```
void CurveGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    if (vertices.size() < 2) {
        return;
    }
    updateVertices();
    glClearColor(m_clearColor.r, m_clearColor.g, m_clearColor.b, m_clearColor.a);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    m_program.bind();
    m_vao.bind();
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, vertices.size());
    m_vao.release();
    m_program.release();
}
```

this is a sample of user clicks:

```
V                X        Y
Vertex[ 0 ]  = [ -0.715,  0.48 ]
Vertex[ 1 ]  = [ -0.5175, 0.08 ]
Vertex[ 2 ]  = [ -0.285,  0.426667 ]
Vertex[ 3 ]  = [ -0.2,   -0.153333 ]
Vertex[ 4 ]  = [ -0.02,   0.64 ]
Vertex[ 5 ]  = [ 0.1425,  0.05 ]
Vertex[ 6 ]  = [ 0.2875,  0.696667 ]
Vertex[ 7 ]  = [ 0.41,    0.03 ]
Vertex[ 8 ]  = [ -0.485, -0.396667 ]
Vertex[ 9 ]  = [ -0.015, -0.37 ]
Vertex[ 10 ] = [ 0.14,    0.316667 ]
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? How can I update my vertices on demand?

The full CurveGLWidget source code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/w6dyP8yi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of `&vertices.begin()` I must use `&vertices.front()`.